# Is there any way to sort changes by time in Gerrit?

Tags: api, sorting, datetime, gerrit

[This document](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html) describes how we can get gerrit commits within a date range. For example,

> project:team/teamx/appx before:2018-1-1 after:2016-12-31

returns the list of all commits of years 2017. However, I see the commits are showing always descending in datetime. I want to sort the list, ascending in datetime.

Is there any way to do so?